# Python take modified list outside for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples

I have been working on a way to make list of tuples and finding the average of each tuples.

```
myList = [(1,2,3),(4,12,6)]
def GS(myList):
     for miniList in myList:
          r = miniList[0]
          g = miniList[1]
          b = miniList[2]
          GS = round((r+g+b)/3,2)
          miniList = list(miniList)
          miniList[0] = GS
          miniList[1] = GS
          miniList[2] = GS
          miniList = tuple(miniList)
     return myList     

 print(GS(myList))
```

my list is [(1,2,3),(4,12,6)]

I should get the average of each tuple and replace the three

output : `[(2.0,2.0,2.0),(7.33,7.33,7.33)]`

Comment: `[[numpy.average(x)]*len(x) for x in original_list]` ?

Comment: Look up tuple unpacking. You can put all those r/g/b and miniList assignments on one line each. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. Below is an example which avoids calculating the length of each tuple twice via `map` and `zip` iterators.

```
myList = [(1,2,3),(4,12,6)]

def GS(L):
    lens = map(len, L)
    res = [(sum(i)/i_len,)*i_len for i, i_len in zip(L, lens)]
    return res

print(GS(myList))

[(2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (7.333333333333333, 7.333333333333333, 7.333333333333333)]
```

If you wish to round decimals, you can use:

```
res = [(round(sum(i)/i_len, 2),)*i_len for i, i_len in zip(L, lens)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do you use the for loop in just one line.

Comment: Don't do it in one line, in my opinion. It's clear and efficient multiline.

Answer (score 2):

```
myList = [(1,2,3),(4,12,6)]
[(round(sum(e)/len(e)),)*len(e) for e in myList]
# [(2.0, 2.0, 2.0), (7.33, 7.33, 7.33)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your `for` loop, you write:

```
 for miniList in myList:
     # ...
     miniList = tuple(miniList)
```

you here seem to want to *assign by reference*. But that is not possible in Python (or at least not with this syntax).

You can however use for example an index, and perform it like:

```
def GS(myList):
     for idx, miniList in enumerate(myList):
          r = miniList[0]
          g = miniList[1]
          b = miniList[2]
          GS = round((r+g+b)/3,2)
          miniList = list(miniList)
          miniList[0] = GS
          miniList[1] = GS
          miniList[2] = GS
          myList[idx] = tuple(miniList)
     return myList
```

That being said, this is a rather complex way to do this. You can for example use:

```
def GS(myList):
     for idx, miniList in enumerate(myList):
          miniList[idx] = (round(sum(miniList)/len(miniList), 2),) * len(miniList)
     return myList
```

This will also work on tuples that contain more or less than three elements. What we do is calculating the `sum(..)` of the `miniList`, and divide that by the `len(..)` of the `miniList` to obtain the average. We then use the `round(.., 2)` function like in the original function.

Next we wrap this in a *singleton tuple*, with `(.., )`, and we then multiply it with the length of the tuple, to obtain a tuple where we repeat the elements in the singleton tuple `len(miniList)` times.

That being said, it is typically more *Pythonic* to construct a *new* list, then to change an existing one. Since it is possible that other variables refer to this list, and now are updated as well.